# insert into mysqli multiple values from foreach loop

Tags: php, mysqli

How to insert multiple value in sql from foreach loop?

(It's inserting me only last value not all, and if I add more values in sql then when in the foreach loop only one value it duplicate my insert data.
How to add unique number in my sql as a order id with each insert?
Here is my code...

```
<?php include'header_nav.php'; ?>


<div class="mainContent_u">
<h1> Your shopping Chart<br/>contains ...</h1>

<table class="show_cart">
<tr>
<th><strong><h3>Book Title</strong></h3></th>
<th><strong><h3>Quantity</strong></h3></th>
<th><strong><h3>Price</strong></h3></th>
<th><strong><h3>Total</strong></h3></th>
</tr>

<?php

require 'connect_db.php';
$totalPrice = 0;

foreach($_POST as $name => $value){

    if(is_numeric($value) && $value != 0 && $name != "submit"){

        $sql = "SELECT id,book, price from add_item  WHERE id = ".$name;
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $price = $row['price'] * $value;
        $price = number_format($price,2);
        $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $price;
        $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice,2);
        $qty = $value;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id,book_name, quantity, price_pb, price_total) VALUES ('" . $row['id'] . "','" . $row['book'] . "','" . $qty . "','" . $row['price'] . "','" . $price . "')";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['book']."</td><td>".$value."</td><td>€".$row['price']."</td><td>€".$price."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<strong><h3>Total Price: €".$totalPrice."</h3></strong>";

?>
    <p><strong>Review your shopping cart and then proceed to checkout.</strong></p>


    <a href="checkout.php"><button class="submit" >Proceed to Checkout</button></a>


     </div>
<?php include'footer.php'; ?>
```

If you need any other info let know.

And aswell, why this else statement is not working.

```
 foreach($_POST as $name => $value){

if(is_numeric($value) && $value != 0 && $name != "submit"){

    $sql = "SELECT id,book, price from add_item  WHERE id = ".$name;
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $price = $row['price'] * $value;
    $price = number_format($price,2);
    $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $price;
    $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice,2);
    $qty = $value;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id,book_name, quantity, price_pb, price_total) VALUES ('" . $row['id'] . "','" . $row['book'] . "','" . $qty . "','" . $row['price'] . "','" . $price . "')";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['book']."</td><td>".$value."</td><td>€".$row['price']."</td><td>€".$price."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}else {header('location:all_books.php');}
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is doing a bunch of requests to your database. I would do something like this:

```
//first create something like: $id_seq= '(1,2,3,56,7674,234)';
$id_seq = implode(',',$POST);
//okay I didn't clean up the Post, but you'll get the picture hopefully :)

//Then pull your request in one go:
$sql = 'SELECT id,book, price from add_item  WHERE id IN (' . $id_seq . ')';
```

This way you save your database a bunch of work. I am not sure if it is less expensive (as in database performance) than using your foreach method but it is a lot of neater coding.

Then calculate in your foreach a new list of data like you did:

```
foreach ($list as $rec){
    $price = $rec['price'] * $_POST[$rec['id']];
    //complete your price and insert it in the orders-table
}
```

As for your redirect-question:

```
else {header('location:all_books.php');}
}
```

It won't work because you might have printed html earlier in the loop. Either print the html OR use a redirect, but not both. You will have to do a check before redirecting.
EDIT: the redirect won't work since you printed html in the top part of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO instead. It save you the headache of SQL injection attacks.

```
<?php include'header_nav.php'; ?>

<div class="mainContent_u">
<h1> Your shopping Chart<br/>contains ...</h1>

<table class="show_cart">
<tr>
    <th><strong><h3>Book Title</strong></h3></th>
    <th><strong><h3>Quantity</strong></h3></th>
    <th><strong><h3>Price</strong></h3></th>
    <th><strong><h3>Total</strong></h3></th>
</tr>

<?php

    require 'connect_db.php';
    $totalPrice = 0;

    foreach($_POST as $name => $value){

    if(is_numeric($value) && $value != 0 && $name != "submit"){

    $sql = "SELECT id,book, price from add_item  WHERE id = ".$name;
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $price = $row['price'] * $value;
        $price = number_format($price,2);
        $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $price;
        $totalPrice = number_format($totalPrice,2);
        $qty = $value;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (order_id,book_name, quantity, price_pb, price_total) VALUES ('" . $row['id'] . "','" . $row['book'] . "','" . $qty . "','" . $row['price'] . "','" . $price . "')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['book']."</td><td>".$value."</td><td>€".$row['price']."</td><td>€".$price."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<strong><h3>Total Price: €".$totalPrice."</h3></strong>";

  ?>
  <p><strong>Review your shopping cart and then proceed to checkout.     </strong></p>


<a href="checkout.php"><button class="submit" >Proceed to Checkout</button></a>


 </div>
<?php include'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Note that; `mysqli` has also prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = "SELECT id,book, price from add_item  WHERE id = ".$name;` Does that give you several lines if you make the request manually ?

Comment: Hi Guys... thanks for your efforts to solve my problem, but I solve it... I use session to add all the orders in the database and then display them where session Id=sessionid ()... much easier